# How to export a project from IBM Bluemix PaaS to anywhere else as a Docker?

Tags: mobile, web, docker, export, ibm-cloud

I lead a web/mobile project and I still need to know the tools we will be using for development.
We have a 6 months access to IBM Bluemix, and its security check tools, CloudFoundry, and others may appear really useful.

However, we don't want to rely on a solution that would trap our project without any possibility of migration if needed.

I looked up on the internet how to export a project from Bluemix as a docker, with elements created from IBM. I didn't find anything relevant (I might be bad at googling, but all I can find is "how to export to Bluemix/how to work locally").

Does Bluemix allow to export the entire project onto another hoster, does it depend on the services we used in the project ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you package your application in a container you can run it on any provider that supports Docker. That could be another cloud, in a local datacenter or on your own laptop.

If you are planning to use Bluemix services as part of that application then you will have two options if moving your application off Bluemix.

1. Keep using the services in Bluemix but connect to them remotely from wherever you're now hosting your appliaction. This will require internet connectivity and you'll have to hard code the service credentials in to your application (not good practice).
2. Migrate the services as well as the application. This will only be possible for the non-unique services IBM offer e.g. Redis, Mongo, Elasticsearch etc.. You'll need to refactor your application to accept the new provider of these services.

Answer (score 0):

If your service/app is dockerized, and is being hosted as a container on Bluemix.
You can pull the container image of your service/app in your own docker enabled cloud or local environment. Following steps can be followed for the same:

1. install bluemix-container cli package https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_ov.html
2. do `cf ic login` using your bluemix credentials
3. check for your images using `cf ic images` command
4. pull the image in your environment using `docker pull <image-registry-url>`
5. run the container with required parameters using `docker run`

Hope it helps. Thanks.